# My master's thesis might be of interest for a specific company. How should I mention it in an application?

Tags: applications

I have just finished my master's thesis which dealt with driver development for a larger company's devices. I believe this work might be interesting for the company since they only recently started their research in this area and are currently actively marketing it. If not, it would at least show that I am more acquainted with their products at a low level than other applicants.

So I thought I should mention it when applying there but I'm not sure to which extent. I'm thinking of three options:

1. Only add the title to the resume.
2. Summarize what I did in a paragraph in the cover letter.
3. Include the complete thesis with the application.
   (I'm aware that nobody will read the complete thesis but it might at least prove that I'm not lying?)

In case you recommend me point #3 I'd need some advice on how to apply: The company seems to advertise open positions only through their own careers portal. Right now, there is one open position which would match very well with what I did in the thesis. However, I'm only able to upload one PDF file (the CV) there. I've found a recruiting@ email address but it seems that it hasn't been used for at least 2 years. The last option would be to send a paper letter (maybe as an unsolicited application) to the general company address but I'm wondering whether this it not too old-fashioned and an overkill because of the extra 80 pages.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: I would choose a variation of option 2. It doesn't have to be a complete paragraph in your cover letter. If you think it's a good selling point, then mention this fact but don't lose sight of the overall goal of the cover letter (sell yourself). In an interview you can talk ad nauseam about the thesis if they find it interesting. Only send the complete thesis on request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is to not rely on the application in a webform to communicate this info nor should you just send a letter to a "general address".

Web-based applications in large companies might not even be read by a human and if they are read by a human it would be HR staff who would see unsolicited technical details as "noise". A paper letter that is not addressed to anyone specific will likely be treated as junk mail and thrown into a bin with equipment catalogs, conference postcards, and vendor advertisements.

Instead, try to find an actual technical peer at the company to communicate with. This can be done in all sorts of informal ways starting with LinkedIn and progressing through alumni networks, cohorts, and friends.

Share what you've done and demonstrate you're interested. Even if it doesn't lead to an invitation to interview for a job, if you handle it right, you can gain valuable information about the job market that you can use to sharpen your hunt.

For your resume/application, just put in a link to the thesis so that interested folks can find it. The research should be a prominent "bullet point" in the resume. Describe the research in your cover letter in a very short paragraph with a focus towards applicability to the company in question.

Answer (score 1):

1 and 2 should be more than sufficient enough. 3 is always possible when people ask for it. Afterall, you did write it.

Comment: Could you maybe go into some more detail about why 1&2 should be sufficient?